# Netbeans "create new C++ project" Finish button, nothing happens

Tags: c++, netbeans, project

I did a fresh install of Netbeans 7.0.1 (with C++ pack). I want to create a new project and after filling in the required fields and pressing on 'Finish', it blinks one time and then nothing happens at all.

[image]

Anyone has a solution found on this?  As you can see, my OS is Windows 7.

Comment: What `JDK` version are you running on your machine?

Comment: I'm running JDK 1.6.0_26

Comment: Does a red exclamation mark pop up in the lower right corner of the main window? If it does, it means that an exception happened and is probably a bug. Well, it smells like a bug anyways.

Comment: Look for an error in `%userprofile%\.netbeans\7.0\var\log\messages.log`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and the log showed a warning and an exception when the project folder was created (see below).
Indeed, changing the project folder solved the problem.

```
Warning:
WARNING [nativeexecution.support.logger]: [2197 ms.] Default tmp dir [C:\Users\PPATRI~1.MET\AppData\Local\Temp\] has spaces/non-latin chars in the path. It is recommended to use a path without spaces/non-latin chars for tmp dir. Either change TEMP environment variable in System Properties or use -J-Djava.io.tmpdir=c:\tmp to change the temp dir.

Exception:

org.openide.filesystems.FileStateInvalidException
    at org.netbeans.modules.masterfs.filebasedfs.fileobjects.RootObjWindows.createFolder(RootObjWindows.java:208)
    at org.netbeans.modules.masterfs.filebasedfs.fileobjects.RootObj.createFolder(RootObj.java:258)
    at org.openide.filesystems.FileUtil.createFolder(FileUtil.java:865)
    at org.netbeans.modules.cnd.makeproject.MakeProjectGeneratorImpl.createProjectDir(MakeProjectGeneratorImpl.java:355)
    at org.netbeans.modules.cnd.makeproject.MakeProjectGeneratorImpl.createProject(MakeProjectGeneratorImpl.java:182)
    at org.netbeans.modules.cnd.makeproject.ui.wizards.NewMakeProjectWizardIterator.instantiate(NewMakeProjectWizardIterator.java:504)
    at org.netbeans.modules.cnd.makeproject.ui.wizards.NewMakeProjectWizardIterator.instantiate(NewMakeProjectWizardIterator.java:395)
    at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizard$InstantiatingIteratorBridge.instantiate(TemplateWizard.java:1046)
    at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizard.handleInstantiate(TemplateWizard.java:617)
    at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizard.instantiateNewObjects(TemplateWizard.java:426)
    at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizardIterImpl.instantiate(TemplateWizardIterImpl.java:252)
    at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizardIteratorWrapper$ProgressInstantiatingIterator.instantiate(TemplateWizardIteratorWrapper.java:180)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor.callInstantiateOpen(WizardDescriptor.java:1566)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor.callInstantiate(WizardDescriptor.java:1521)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor.access$1800(WizardDescriptor.java:139)
[catch] at org.openide.WizardDescriptor$Listener$2$1.run(WizardDescriptor.java:2134)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1411)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:1991)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try changing the directory you are saving the project in - if this doesn't work, try reinstalling Netbeans.

Or try clicking on finish. When it blinks, close the new project window and then check if the project has been created. Sometimes programs have this bug where it creates the project, but doesn't close the Create New Project Window/ inform the user.

I am speaking from experience- this happened to me a couple of weeks ago, and reinstalling Netbeans worked for me.

PS: Any IDE errors are logged in %userprofile%.netbeans\7.0\var\log\messages.log
Check it out if you come to a dead end.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem occurred for me, changing the project folder location solved the issue. But while changing I came to know that window were making the project folder read-only automatically. So thats why the issue is coming up. And its windows 7 bug and not netbeans bug !!

Create a new folder and check its properties, you will see that it is read-only. Microsoft says its because your user account is corrupted.For removing the bug, either you have to make a new user account with admin rights and use that or replace OS. Just google how to solve the bug.

Answer (score 0):

### I got this error to happen in Fedora 17

I'm using Java version `1.7.0_25`

**How to reproduce**

1. Open netbeans.  Choose File -> New Project.
2. Select C/C++ ->  C++ Application
3. Click next.  You get this screen.  Click FINISH.
   [image]
4. Nothing happens.  You see the error happen in lower right.
5. Close the new C/C++ Application window and click the red error icon.  You get this:

[image]

6. Clicking on "Show Details" you get a mountain of netbeans code guts spewed all over.
7. Netbeans IDE Bug!  So how do we fix it?

### SOLUTION 1, delete the .netbeans ide configuration directory

The problem is some kind of inconsistency in your `.netbeans` ide configuration folder.  One way to fix it is to stop netbeans, delete that directory, then restart netbeans.  The `.netbeans` directory will be re-created and set to defaults.

Steps:

1. Close netbeans.
2. Make a copy of all your critical programs you want to keep.  Make a copy of your `.netbeans` ide configuration folder.
3. Delete the `/home/el/NetbeansProjects` directory where netbeans stores your programs.
4. Delete the `/home/el/.netbeans` directory which has configuration info for the IDE.
5. Start Netbeans.  It will be as if it was started new for the first time and everything will work.

### SOLUTION 2, open netbeans as different user.

Opening netbeans as a new user will create a new `.netbeans` folder.  And works for same reason as above.

Walkthrough:

1. First you need to know how to run netbeans on the terminal, find out like this:
2. Right click my Application launcher -> Edit applications.
3. Locate the Netbeans icon launcher for netbeans.  Click edit
4. The run field says  `/bin/sh "/usr/local/netbeans-7.3/bin/netbeans"`
5. OK, so now login as root, add user foobar and set password:

   ```
   el@defiant $ su
   Password: 

   [root@defiant bin]# useradd foobar

   [root@defiant bin]# passwd foobar
   Changing password for user foobar.
   New password: 
   passwd: all authentication tokens updated successfully.
   ```
6. exit super user and login as foobar on terminal:

   ```
   [root@defiant bin]# exit
   exit
   el@defiant $ su foobar
   Password:
   ```
7. Then run netbeans as foobar:

   ```
   [foobar@defiant bin]$ /bin/sh "/usr/local/netbeans-7.3/bin/netbeans"
   ```
8. Netbeans comes up, fresh and new!  Now everything works normally.